# Помогите разобраться с алгоритмом сортировки слиянием

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка

Решил в целях обучения посмотреть алгоритм сортировки слиянием, алгоритм реализации вполне понятен, а вот с самой  реализацией - не получилось, на просторах интернета нашел вот такой пример:

```
 public void StartMethod()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] unsortedArray = new int[85];
        for(var i = 0; i < unsortedArray.Length; i ++)
        {
            unsortedArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        }
        MergeSort(unsortedArray, 1, unsortedArray.Length - 1);
        foreach(int element in unsortedArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }  
    }   

    private void MergeSort(int[] unsortedArray, int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {

        if(leftIndex < rightIndex)
        {
            int middleIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;
            MergeSort(unsortedArray, leftIndex, middleIndex);
            MergeSort(unsortedArray, middleIndex + 1, rightIndex);
            Merge(unsortedArray, leftIndex, middleIndex, rightIndex);
        }
    }   

    private void Merge(int[] unsortedArray, int leftIndex, int middleIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
        int lengthLeft = middleIndex - leftIndex + 1;
        int lengthRight = rightIndex - middleIndex;
        int[] leftArray = new int[lengthLeft + 1];
        int[] rightArrray = new int[lengthRight + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < lengthLeft; i ++)
        {
            leftArray[i] = unsortedArray[leftIndex + i];
        }
        for(int j =0; j < lengthRight; j++)
        {
            rightArrray[j] = unsortedArray[middleIndex + j + 1];
        }

        leftArray[lengthLeft] = int.MaxValue;
        rightArrray[lengthRight] = int.MaxValue;

        int iIndex = 0;
        int jIndex = 0;

        for (int k = leftIndex; k <= rightIndex; k ++)
        {
            if(leftArray[iIndex] <= rightArrray[jIndex])
            {
                unsortedArray[k] = leftArray[iIndex];
                iIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                unsortedArray[k] = rightArrray[jIndex];
                jIndex++;
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

в принципе вроде все понятно за исключением одного момента,зачем в методе *Merge* делается следующее:

```
        leftArray[lengthLeft] = int.MaxValue;
        rightArrray[lengthRight] = int.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечу чуть упрощённо. Будет считать что все наши сортируемые элементы строго меньше чем `int.MaxValue`.

Мы не должны брать элементы с индексом большим, чем размер массива.
Обычно это делается изменением компаратора `if(leftArray[iIndex] <= rightArrray[jIndex])` на `if(jIndex==rightArrray.size() || leftArray[iIndex] <= rightArrray[jIndex])` но для простоты можно использовать метод как выше. Тогда самый крайний элемент массива будет больше всех остальных и следовательно никогда не будет выбран.